# Where does the coolant go?

Tags: coolant

I filled up the coolant a few months ago and today I found the coolant level is near MIN. Is it normal that coolant "evaporates" over time? Or does it mean that it is leaking somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not normal. If it happens over the course of a couple of months, it probably means that there is a very tiny leak somewhere and when the coolant gets hot enough, some of it escapes as steam. Check your cap's tightness first.

Or if you're unlucky and your car recently overheated, it may have caused your head gasket to blow in such a way that coolant gets sucked into the cylinder and is expelled through the exhaust, but that usually drinks up the coolant fairly quickly.

Comment: Your mechanic should have a tester that will check for hydrocarbons in your coolant, and this indicates you have a blown head gasket.  Just don't pour any of the various brands of miracle head gasket fixer into your coolant tank unless you really don't care about ruining the car.  That stuff keeps a lot of radiator repair shops in business.